# VueJS/Vuetify - @change set loading="true" on input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a method, which is triggered by `@change` on multiple inputs.

I need to set `loading="true"` for the target input until `axios` finishes the request (PATCH).

NOTE:

There are multiple `v-select` on the page and I want to set loading=true just for the one particular target - the current input/select.

---

EXAMPLE:

If the user selects an option in the first select in the example below, the `inlineUpdate` method is called which modifies the target to looks like this `<v-select loading="true" @change="$root.inlineUpdate" ...`

and then, after the `update` is finished, it removes the `loading` attribute.

---

I suppose I need `event` argument passed into the method but it doesn't work.

It passes just a value so I can't recognize which input should I set as being loaded.

```
 <v-select @change="$root.inlineUpdate" ...
 <v-select @change="$root.inlineUpdate" ...
 <v-select @change="$root.inlineUpdate" ...
 <v-text-field @change="$root.inlineUpdate"...

 inlineUpdate(event){
              console.log(event)
              console.log(event.target)
             # here I need to set loading="true" for the input
             axios.post(...).finally(() => { // remove the loading })
             # stop loading
            },
```

logs

```
>>> house
>>> undefined
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Why can't you just do `this.loading = true`, then do your request, and set `this.loading = false` with a `.finally()` for the request? Side note, which is **very** important... You should not be using `$root` this way. [It is not good practice](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Root-Instance) for the majority of applications

Comment: I want the loading set just for the exact input. Not for the whole app.

Comment: So create a variable in your `data` object for the component, which binds to the v-select loading attribute. And set that variable as needed. No need to make it any more complicated for yourself.

Comment: The input/select itself can have attribute loading=true which makes only this particular input to be animated (loading). I don't want a loading across the whole screen.

Comment: There are many selects which can trigger change event.

Comment: Like here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/inputs/#loading

Comment: Please update your question with *all* relevant code to answer the question. If you have more than one select, then include that in your question.

Comment: @EvanBechtol I think it's written multiple times there that I want that for the particular input.

Comment: We can't guess what the rest of your code looks like. You are saying that there are multiple `v-select`. We need to know what the entirety of the code looks like to solve the problem. I provided a solution that works for "that particular input", but you said you have multiple selects that this should also work for. If this is inside of a `v-for`, you could pass the index to your method as well, which would aid in setting the select loading attribute.

Comment: @EvanBechtol Ok, I've edited the question. I hope it's clear now. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like the `v-on:change` only supplies the `value` of the Vuetify input and it never exposes the underlying `Event`, making it impossible to access `event.target`, for example: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/inputs/#api.

Comment: @Terry I know that and that's the problem but I hope there are ways to do that. The only think I can think of is to create a watcher which watches the v-model object for this selects and then somehow detect the changed field and somehow get the particular component...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a separate variable that handles loading for only the `v-select`. So we create one called `isSelectLoading`, which defaults to false. Then, when we begin our API call process, we set it to `true` and once the promise resolves we set it back to `false`.

```js
<v-select label="Typ nehnuteľnosti" :loading="isSelectLoading"  @change="$root.inlineUpdate" ...

...
 data: () => ({
   isSelectLoading: false
 }),
 methods: {
   inlineUpdate(){
     this.isSelectLoading = true;
     axios.put("/some/url", ...)
        .then(apiResponse => { //do some stuff })
        .catch(apiError => { //oh no! })
        .finally(() => { this.isSelectLoading = false });
   },
 }
```

### Update for multiple `v-selects`

You need a way to keep track of which components are loading. We will handle that with an array called `isSelectLoading`. It will be in our data property, and we are defaulting the loading state to `false`.

You also need a way to know which `v-select` is being changed. To take care of that, we will create another variable called `activeSelect`. We will bind this to our `v-select` via the `@click` event listener.

Then, when we change a selection from any of our selects, we can update our loading state only for that `v-select`!

```js
 <v-select 
    @change="inlineUpdate" 
    @click="activeSelect = 0"
    :loading="isSelectLoading[0]"...
 <v-select 
    @change="inlineUpdate" 
    @click="activeSelect = 1"
   :loading="isSelectLoading[1]"...
 <v-select 
    @change="inlineUpdate" 
    @click="activeSelect = 2"
    :loading="isSelectLoading[2]"...
 <v-text-field
    @change="inlineUpdate" 
    @click="activeSelect = 3"
    :loading="isSelectLoading[3]"...

 ...
  data: () => ({
    activeSelect: null,
    items: ["a", "b", "c"],
    isSelectLoading: [false, false, false]
  }),
 methods: {
   inlineUpdate(){
     this.toggleLoading(this.activeSelect);
     axios.put("/some/url", ...)
        .then(apiResponse => { //do some stuff })
        .catch(apiError => { //oh no! })
        .finally(() => { this.toggleLoading(this.activeSelect); });
   },
   toggleLoading(index) {
     this.isSelectLoading[index] = !this.isSelectLoading[index]
   }
```

In this example it's a bit trivialized; in real code, we could put these inside of a `<template v-for="(item, index) in selects">...`, where `selects` would have the required fields/properties in order to generate your select components. You would replace the hard-coded indexes with the value of `index` for the event bindings.

Comment: In this solution, I don't know which select is loading so I can't set <v-select loading... I don't know which v-select should have set this attribute.

Comment: @Milano If you have more than one select, you are going to have to update your question with *all* relevant code to solve the problem.

Comment: yes, I did it slightly differently but yes, this is a good solution, thanks.